# Regarding Degrees and Calculation of time

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the Angle between the time 4.30 pm in clock, what is the Angle? please share the Answer answer like 40 degree, 60 degree etc like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  The minute hand moves $360^\circ$ in one hour, so at $4:30$ it has moved $180^\circ$ from straight up.  The hour hand moves $360^\circ$ in $12$ hours, so at $4:30$ it has moved $\frac {4.5}{12}\cdot 360^\circ$ degrees from straight up.  Now subtract.